# Adblocker - Catch net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Tags: javascript, jquery, adblock

I am trying to fetch a number of scripts and then run an initialize function which works fine if a user does not have an ad blocker on but if there is an ad blocker the `ads-script.js` gets blocked with a `net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` and my `.done` callback never gets fired and so the js on my page never gets initialized. I've tried to have fail/error callbacks for both the `$.getScript` and `$.when` functions but they dont get hit either. Does anyone know of a way to catch the blocked get script call (or something along those lines), handle that error and ensure that the `done` callback gets hit. Thanks

```
$.when(
   $.getScript( "http://example.com/script1.js" ),
   $.getScript( "http://example.com/script2.js" ),
   $.getScript("http://example.com/ads-script.js"),
   $.Deferred(function( deferred ){
       $( deferred.resolve );
   })
 ).done(function() {
   console.log('here');
   initialize();
 });
```

Comment: Anything with `ad` keyword gets captured by proxy adblockers. Workaround is to use not so obvious name of the script.

Comment: definitely agree, unfortunately its a 3rd party script and I have no control over the naming convention.

Comment: Have you tried removing that script and see if your code works as is? If so then you can just have ad script owner to rename it to something else or just have it hosted on your server as a different name

Comment: `Does anyone know of a way to catch the blocked get script`  I hope not, if someone has put an add-blocker on, and your trying to prevent your users wishes,, shame on you..

Comment: The code works without the script, just an ad-on to initialize if there is no ad-blocker. have tried to have owner rename it but they will not do it. could host but would rather not try and keep up with any and all updates/patches etc.

Comment: @Keith certainly not trying to prevent a users wishes, just don't want an adblock to prevent users from utilizing (non ad related) functionalities.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `.fail()` to your getScript?

Comment: yeah I've tried adding  `.fail()` to the getScript and the fail does not get hit. i've also tried adding something like `$.when( $.getScript( "script1.js" ), $.getScript( "ad-script.js" ) )
  .then( myFunc, myFailure );` and the myFailure callback does not get called either

Comment: is the script on your server? Your code seems to indicate that it is... in which case renaming it should be trivial. If it isn't, that would explain why you can't track the error.

Comment: the script is not on my server

Answer (score 1):

Very old post but I would like to share this.

```
 var sc = document.createElement("script");
 sc.setAttribute("src", "https://yourhost/advertisement/ads.js");
 sc.setAttribute("onerror", "someAction()");
 sc.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
 sc.setAttribute("onload", "someAction()");
 document.head.appendChild(sc);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$.when` returns a jQuery `Promise`. If you want to capture errors from this, use `.fail()`:

```
$.when(
   $.getScript( "http://example.com/script1.js" ),
   $.getScript( "http://example.com/script2.js" ),
   $.getScript("http://example.com/ads-script.js"),
   $.Deferred(function( deferred ){
       $( deferred.resolve );
   })
 ).done(function() {
   console.log('here');
   initialize();
 }).fail(function(err) {
   console.log('i am an error handler', err)
 });
```

Comment: for me the `.fail()` never gets hit and so i cannot capture the error and then handle it appropriately. Maybe `ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` errors somehow bypass `.fail()`? i am unsure